# Sort list of strings by the numbers at the front of the string

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a leaderboard and the way I'm organizing it is like this:

```
leaderboard=['-7\tPlayerName','6\tPlayerName','2\tPlayerName','-11\tPlayerName']
```

The problem is that when I do `leaderboard.sort()`, it doesn't put them in the order that I want. I know there is probably a better way to do this. If you can think of one, please let me know. But I prefer to do it this way. My ultimate goal is that after I sort it, it should look like this:

```
leaderboard=['-11\tPlayerName','-7\tPlayerName','2\tPlayerName','6\tPlayerName']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [260]: leaderboard=['-7\tPlayerName','6\tPlayerName','2\tPlayerName','-11\tPlayerName']

In [261]: sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda x: int(x.split('\t')[0]))
Out[261]: ['-11\tPlayerName', '-7\tPlayerName', '2\tPlayerName', '6\tPlayerName']

In [262]: leaderboard.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('\t')[0]))
KeyboardInterrupt

In [262]: leaderboard
Out[262]: ['-7\tPlayerName', '6\tPlayerName', '2\tPlayerName', '-11\tPlayerName']

In [263]: leaderboard.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('\t')[0]))

In [264]: leaderboard
Out[264]: ['-11\tPlayerName', '-7\tPlayerName', '2\tPlayerName', '6\tPlayerName']
```